# Поиск индекса в List

Tags: c#, indexof

Есть класс:

```
public class ProductPit
{
    public ProductPit(string prod, double cena, string ediz)
    {
       Prod = prod;
       Cena = cena;
       EdIz = ediz;
    }

    public string Prod { get; set; }
    public double Cena { get; set; }
    public string EdIz { get; set; }
}
```

Я создаю список с элементами ProductPit

```
List<ProductPit> prpit =  new List<ProductPit>;
```

Как мне в списке найти номер записи в которой: `prpit.Prod == "Колбаса"`
Знаю что есть IndexOf, но как его использовать в данном случае не пойму(

Comment: p=>p.Prod == "..." - выдает ошибку "Невозможно преобразовать "лямбда-выражение" к типу ProductPit, поскольку он не является делегатом.

Comment: Верно, потому что тот ответ нерабочий, посмотрите мой. ЗЫ. Пишите комментарии под тем постом к которому они относятся, иначе автор их не увидит.

Comment: Да, это был мой косяк - я отправил не весь код. Согласен с @Андрей, ответ был так себе, потому я его удалил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [`FindIndex()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x1xzf2ca(v=vs.110).aspx)

Он принимает предикат, которой проверит ваше условие:

```
int index = list.FindIndex(x => x.Prod == "Колбаса");
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, все работает!

Comment: @camtasia, слева от поста под стрелочками для голосования есть галочка чтобы принять ответ.

Comment: я уже более-менее разобрался что к чему здесь, просто в дополнении благодарность оставляю))

Comment: @camtasia, пожалуйста, рад помочь.